# Effective wavelength

Tags: wavelength, photometry

While measuring light from sky or anyother things we use photometer.  If current flowing in photometer is proportional to intensity and frequency why there is something called effective wavelengths.  What cause an instrument to effective to particular wavelength or frequency?

Comment: Silicon is used in a CCD camera chip, this material has a specific band gap that is good at absorbing in the visible spectrum.  Some materials have a band gap in the IR spectrum and some have no band gap at all.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand the question.
When the light of an object arrives on your telescope, it passes through a filter. Every filter has its response, that is in function of the wavelength.
In addition, the quantum efficiency is to be considered, also in function of the wavelength.

When you have considered all these parameters, you can calculate the effective wavelength, that is a "central value" that take into account all these parameters.